# Set featured image as hero image on each page

Tags: posts, post-thumbnails

I want my post's featured image show as a full width hero image.
I have tried to set the featured images as background images in a full-width row, but I think it is not possible.

If anyone have the answer or a way to set the featured image as a hero, then please suggest.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/359191/edit) to specify what you've tried and what specific problems you're having. Relevant code samples will make it much easier to assist you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to look at how your theme is rendering the hero image. Then, before it does so, add an if block which checks for a featured image. If a featured image exists, replace the hero image with it. Your code will look something like this.

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
  // render hero image using the_post_thumbnail() instead
}
```

Comment: Thank You for the answer